# Image is getting uploaded to the folder but not getting displayed - php upload image

Tags: php

I am trying to make the user upload the image and from my app and I am trying to upload it to the uploads folder. I have shown the folder structure below). I am able to save the image in the respective folder correctly and also able to store the name of the image-file into DB, but when I am trying to show that image into the user account, I am not able to make it visible. I think I am messing up with the PATH.

Folder structure:

- htdocs

  - demo_app

    - app

      - config

        - config.php
      - controllers
      - core
      - views
      - models
      - uploads
      - userImage
      - .htaccess
    - public (This is a root folder)

      - assets

        - css
        - js
        - images
        - uploads
        - userImage
      - index.php (This is a root index file)
      - .htaccess
    - vendors
    - .htaccess

So with the above folder structure, I have tried couple of things:

1. Uploading the image to the userImage folder (app/uploads/userImage/), and I was able to upload an image successfully to this folder. But when I tried to display it, I am not getting any image.
2. I also tried uploading and storing the image to the userImage folder (/public/assets/uploads/userImage/), but this time I was not even successful to store it in the folder.

Following code snippets is from both of my tries.

**config.php**

```
<?php 

 $site_url = '/';
 define('SITE_URL', $site_url);
 define('APP_ROOT',dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); // (Path to 'app' folder)
 define('URL_ROOT', 'http://localhost/demo-app');

 // Following path is to upload image to public/assets/uploads/) folder
 define('UPLOAD_PATH', 
 dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/public/assets/uploads");
```

**controller (userController.php)**

```
$img_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$upload_folder = APP_ROOT . "/uploads/userImage/" . $img_name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $upload_folder);

// The above uploading code works perfect for me to upload the image to app/uploads/userImage/ folder

// Following code doesn't work for me to upload it to the public/assets/uploads/userImage folder
 //Approach 2

 $upload_folder = UPLOAD_PATH . "/userImage/" . $img_name;
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $upload_folder);
```

**View (index.php) **(app/views/users/index.php)

```
// Following for showing image from app uploads folder

  <?php $img_path = APP_ROOT . "/uploads/userImage/" . $user->image ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $img_path; ?>">

// Following for showing image from public uploads folder

  <?php $img_path = URL_ROOT . "/assets/uploads/userImage/" . $user->image ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $img_path; ?>">
```

I think I have problem with the PATHs, so if anyone can help me with this, it would be great. Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file userController.php is inside the controllers folder. Change your first part to

```
$img_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$upload_folder = "../uploads/userImage/" . $img_name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $upload_folder);
```

and change your second path to

```
$upload_folder = "../../public/assets/uploads/userImage/" . $img_name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $upload_folder);
```

For displaying, your file is in `app/views/users/index.php`, so do this

```php
<?php $img_path = "../../uploads/userImage/" . $user->image ?>
<img src="<?php echo $img_path; ?>">

<?php $img_path = URL_ROOT . "/assets/uploads/userImage/" . $user->image ?>
<img src="<?php echo $img_path; ?>">
```

Comment: I tried that too, but that didnot worked either. And also while researching I found that, to upload the image and to save it to the folder on the server, we need to use directory Path(UPLOAD_PATH here) and to display that image, you need to give URL to that folder, like you would give to any other css or js or image files.

Comment: I made a major edit @JohnCaverns check and do tell me